# Plotting pareto fronts for vectors

Tags: algorithm, matlab, optimization

I'm trying to use MatLab to extract the Pareto frontier of a vector of random numbers, which would be the set of non-dominated solutions and would ideally be non-convex. So, for each x entry, I'm trying to check the value of each y entry and determine if it would qualify as a non-dominated solution. It would qualify as a non-dominated solution if the value of that y entry was greater than the maximum of y entries that had come before it. And I would want to plot any of these non-dominated solutions. I have been trying to do this in a for or while loop, like in my code below, but I'm stuck. I would appreciate any assistance about where to go from here :)

```
 x=rand(113,1)
 y=rand(113,1)
 x=sort(x, 'descend')
 v=[x,y]
 for i=1:113
     m=max(v(i,2))
         if v(i,2) > m
         n=max(v(i,2))
     end 
 end
```

Comment: I believe you would want to replace `m=max(v(i,2))` by `m=max(v(1:i-1,2))` and start your loop from `i = 2`, otherwise you will always compare the current element to itself. Not sure where you are trying to go with the `n=max...`. Here I would just save the indices for which `v(i,2) > m == true`

Comment: Would there be anything else you'd change?

Comment: I am not sure why you have to sort x initially, but apart from that the script should do what you want with those changes.